# IONIC 4 View Documents inside App, works on WEB but not on ANDROID and iOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, iframe

I have an IONIC 4 APP that i need to load document files from storage using API.

I have managed to open IMAGES, WORD Documents, PDFs on WEB, but I am Struggling on iOS and Android.

On iOS files are opened but only the first page, can’t scroll on different pages, while on Android it shows blank page.

this goes with word documents and PDF files, images are opening well, while on web when running ionic serve it is all working well.

For this I have used `iFrame`, I am opening files via `DomSanitizer` using `URLSearchParams` `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`, I also need to do pinch and zoom on `iFrame` but that cant seem to be possible.

If you have any other way that you suggest that would also be worth a try please let me know.

This is iFrame.html:

```
<div class="iframe-fix">
 <iframe
     [src]="iFrameFileSelected"
     frameborder="0"
     webkitallowfullscreen
     mozallowfullscreen
     allowfullscreen
     width="100%"
     height="550px"
     zooming="true"
     scrolling="yes"
   ></iframe>
 </div>
```

and this is .ts file of the iframe

```
iFrameFileSelected: SafeResourceUrl | SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl  = null;



params: any = {
    id: null,
    uuid: null,
    token: null
  };

constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.iFrameFileSelected = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.getMedia + paramsii);
}
```

Thank you very much.

[This is with ionic serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q9jf.png)

[This is running on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyrM5.jpg)

[and this is on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV1uK.png)

Comment: Hi, i opening pdf files on ionic but not on the app... But, your app layout do look really good. Congrats. One qustion, I'm using degrade color as you on header and on iphone it connects really good with navbar. How did you manage to do it on android?

Comment: @jcmendes98, i used on App Component for both: 
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
        this.statusBar.styleLightContent();